# json load JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have problem with json file, this is my code:

```
import json
x= '{ "receive_time": "2020-06-26T08:04:27+07:00", "services": "", "request_uri": "/", "request_body": "{\x22p\x22:\x22smaet\x22,\x22av\x22:\x225.9.0\x22}"}'
json.loads(x)
```

detail error : Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 103 (char 102)
my resutl i want :

```
{'receive_time': '2020-06-26T08:04:27+07:00',
 'services': '',
 'request_uri': '/',
 'request_body': '{"p":"smaet","av":"5.9.0"}'}
```

please help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

String value of `request_body` is malformatted.

As a json string, `\x22` (a double quote) must have a backslash escape.
https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Backslash is an escape character in Python string literal, too. Escape sequence `\\` in a string literal means a single character `\`.

So the following code

```
import json
x = '{ "receive_time": "2020-06-26T08:04:27+07:00", "services": "", "request_uri": "/", "request_body": "{\\\x22p\\\x22:\\\x22smaet\\\x22,\\\x22av\\\x22:\\\x225.9.0\\\x22}"}'
print(json.loads(x))
```

prints

```
{'receive_time': '2020-06-26T08:04:27+07:00', 'services': '', 'request_uri': '/', 'request_body': '{"p":"smaet","av":"5.9.0"}'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use 3 slashes in your string before x222 as the one \ is for special sequences. Two slashes for accepting a single slash and 3 slashes for your desired output.

```
import json
x= '{ "receive_time": "2020-06-26T08:04:27+07:00", "services": "", "request_uri": "/","request_body": "{\\\x22p\\\x22:\\\x22smaet\\\x22,\\\x22av\\\x22:\\\x225.9.0\\\x22}"}'
data = json.loads(x)
print(data);
```

Comment: hi when i use : x.replace('\x22','\\\x22') then x become : '{\\"request_body\\": \\"{\\"p\\":\\"smaet\\",\\"av\\":\\"5.9.0\\"}\\"}' .